# A modification of the NMAC construction

Tags: mac, pseudo-random-permutation, merkle-damgaard

Consider the NMAC construction:

[image]

This is a proposed exercise in my notes:

> Assume F is a PRP with $n = l(n)$. Is it secure to replace $k_0$ by $F_{0^n}(k_0)$ and $k_i$ by $F_{0^n}(k_i)$?

In principle, I think I should prove it is not secure. My second guess is that probably I should find some non-prefix free query. However, I didn't find a solution. Any hints?

Here is my definition of PRP:

[image]

Comment: Suppose $k_0$ is uniformly distributed.  if $F$ is a PRP, what is the distribution on $F_{0^n}(k_0)$?

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage it should be uniform but for a negligible probability. Does this means that the MAC is still secure?

Comment: What is that negligible probability?  (Hint: It is a very simple constant.  Is the _pseudorandom_ property of the PRP even relevant?)

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage The definition of PRP tells me, that any distinguisher should have negligible advantage in distinguishing it from a RPO. Of course, this pseudorandom property would be not relevant if i assume i have a strong PRP and in that case I could say $F_{0^n}(k_0)$ has a uniform distribution. If you can confirm me this is your line of thougth then I guess that with this we are proving that it is as secure as F-NMAC and thus is a secure MAC for $F$ a PRP.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage If the above is correct probably a PRP is required in this setting to avoid collision of $F_{0^n}(k_i)$ and $F_{0^n}(k_o)$

Comment: Besides being ‘pseudorandom’, what else makes a PRP a PRP?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89936/discussion-between-javier-and-squeamish-ossifrage).